# Ctypes: access violation writing

Tags: python, ctypes

I was looking at some functions of ctypes and I came across this problem:

```
import ctypes

hello = open("hello.exe")
shellcode = hello.read()

shellcode_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(shellcode, len(shellcode))

shellcode_func = ctypes.cast(shellcode_buffer, ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p))

shellcode_func()
```

I created hello.exe from powershell in this way

```
Add-Type -outputtype consoleapplication -outputassembly helloworld.exe 'public class helloworld{public static void Main(){System.Console.WriteLine("hello world");}}'
```

running the python I get this error

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x70098553
```

Comment: That function does not look like C.  Are you sure that is compatible with `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE`?  For a start, it should use use the standard C calling convention, `cdecl`, what you supply is probably `stdcall`.  Try `ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE` instead.